# Windows update doesn't work

Tags: windows, updates

For a week now my Windows computer hasn't downloaded any updates.
I think it may be because of a registry cleaning software called "Uniblue Powersuite"; what do you think may be causing this?

Comment: It should give you an 8-digit hex code error message. Please post that, and we might be able to help.

Comment: there is not any digit

Comment: If you check for updates manually, one of three things should happen. There may not be any updates; the updates will succeed; or you'll get the hex error code. That hex code will help diagnose the problem. Could you check manually and see what happens.